# How to disable the angular select dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to disable the angular select dropdown.  Actually I want restrict the access for few users.
Code link:http://plnkr.co/edit/mGnpQynWKkRLBC0VEHBR?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In controller add:

```
$scope.isDisabled = false; // change to true to disable the multiselect
```

Then, the view should be (look at the *disabled* attribute):

```
<multiselect class="input-xlarge" multiple="true"
    ng-model="selectedCar"
    options="c.name for c in cars"
    change="selected()" disabled="isDisabled"></multiselect>
```

Finally, add the proper logic to set the $scope.isDisabled in your controller.

Comment: HI Thanks for your suggestion,

But i tried the same above solution but wont work it for me may be i put the controller not proper place.

can you tell where i have to add controller in the bellow code
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.multiselect']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.cars = [{id:1, name: 'Audi'}, {id:2, name: 'BMW'}, {id:1, name: 'Honda'}];
    $scope.selectedCar = [];

    $scope.fruits = [{id: 1, name: 'Apple'}, {id: 2, name: 'Orange'},{id: 3, name: 'Banana'}];
    $scope.selectedFruit = null;
});

Comment: Please, reread my answer. I just forked your plnkr that include my modifications: http://plnkr.co/edit/oWPIPH5XVPI7UNZsB2Gz?p=preview

Comment: but as you can also see the output in plunkr it's not working.

It should be disabled right

Comment: change $scope.isDisabled to true in your controller and it will be disabled

Comment: Hi i have one more question.

Actually this mainly i have to used for this logic when the admin is opened all fields will be accessible. when other users access i want disable for specific users can you give any solution for this

Comment: @alle I am facing the same problem and I exactly did what you told still no luck could you please help   this is my question url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066858/not-able-to-disable-a-multi-select-drop-down

Comment: @shv22 Glad you found out the solution.

Comment: @alle yeah me too ;)