# filter the second selectbox based on the first selected option using angular js

Tags: arrays, angularjs, select, nested, ng-options

i have 2 select boxes,which is getting the data using ng-options and hardcoded. 
the second select box should show the data based on the selected data in first selectbox. this is the plunker. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/r1S1e61H3RfH3uYGYTBP?p=preview 
can anyone please help me.

```
$scope.data = [{
        cities: [{
            id: 1,
            title: 'Mysore'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Bangalore'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Delhi'
        }, {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Mumbai'
        }],
        maps: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Zoo',
                city_id: 1
            }, {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Palace',
                city_id: 1
            }, {
                id: 3,
                title: 'Beach',
                city_id: 4
            }]

    }];
```

Comment: plunker has issues like the Cities drop down does not show any data and in HTML file you declared app name as ``myApp`` but in JS file its ``plunker``.

Comment: Sorry, the plunker is updated now. please check https://plnkr.co/edit/r1S1e61H3RfH3uYGYTBP?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the selected city's id from 1st drop down as a filter to 2nd drop down like below

`<select name="mapSelect" required="true" ng-options="map as map.title for map in data[0].maps | filter:{'city_id':citySelect.selectedOption.id}" ng-model="mapSelect.selectedOption"></select>`

Comment: i had the same query. This solution works. Thanks.
One more query is how to disable the maps until the city is selected

Comment: @Gautam - Pls Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514921/how-to-disable-the-angular-select-dropdown for enabling / disabling drop down.

Comment: one more thing.
i need to draw the google map based on city selected here. can you tell me how

Comment: @ThilakRaj , i don not much about it :-(