# Not able to disable a multi-select drop down

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

Hi I am new to AngularJs. Here my problem is on a certain condition I need to disable my multiselect dropdown.

So, I made the logic and on with the help of I tried to disable the dropdown-

```
document.getElementById("multidropdown").disabled = true;
```

But no luck.

So, then I google it and get to know about ng-disable. So, I put a ng-disable there and give it a name like this

```
ng-disabled="makeItDisabled"
```

And in my js file, I set

```
$scope.makeItDisabled = false
```

And in the condition, I made the same

```
$scope.makeItDisabled = true
```

But still got no luck.

This is my HTML-

```
column type="dropdownMultiSelect" styleName="form-control ng-isolate-scope multidropdown" ng-dropdown-multiselect=""  options="dropdownData" selectedmodel="dropdownelect" extrasettings="multiselectsettings"  events="DropDown_changed" text=""  uniqueID="multidropdown" ng-disabled=" makeItDisabled
```

This is my js code which I have tried

```
document.getElementById("multidropdown").disabled = true;
```

and also

```
$scope.makeItDisabled = true;
```

I did the same with the disabled also but there also I was not able to do it. I want to know where I am getting it wrong.

I am using this 
[https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect](http://Github%20Mutiselect)

Comment: are you using any plugin for multiselect dropdown?

Comment: I think you are using isolate scope on select and then taking the parent controller scope variable to disable it that why your code is not working

Comment: Try for `$scope.makeItDisabled = { isDisable: true}` and `ng-disabled = "makeItDisabled.isDisable"`

Comment: @MayankPatel no I am not using

Comment: @ARUN I tried its not working

Comment: Added the URL of github from where I am using the multiselect

Answer (score 5):

Finally I was able to do it by just using css

I disabled the dropdown by using

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  <ng-multiselect-dropdown 
       [placeholder]="' '" [data]="myList"
       [(ngModel)]="mySelectedItems" [settings]="mySettings"
       (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
       (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" 
       (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)"
       [disabled]=!isToDisable()>
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: Please explain what the code in your answer does and why it might help. See [How-To-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-disabled not ngdisabled and it should work. Post further if you have any queries

Comment: sorry mistake it was already ng-disabled. I posted it correctly again thanks for pointing